# Correlation by group and test for significant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, cross-correlation

My data has the following form:

```
  name  val1  val2
0    a     1     2
1    a     2     5
2    a     3     7
3    b     4    11
4    b     5    13
5    b     6    17
6    b     7    19
7    c     8    23
8    c     9    29
9    c    10    31
```

I want to calculate the correlation between `val1` and `val2` by group, then average them.

My question is: what is the formula for a test of this correlation by group?

Hypothesis: average correlation = 0

Comment: What is the null hypothesis you want to test? That all correlations within groups are the same?

Comment: @ChristianHennig: I just edited. I want to test average correlation is = 0. However, I also want to ask if it is logic to test hypothesis correl < 0.3 to conclude that they have weak correlation?

Comment: Chances are there is no standard test for this. One may construct something using a bootstrap or permutation approach; and that may not be so easy here. Anyway, "Hypothesis: average correlation=0" is still somewhat imprecise. Are you assuming all groups of the same size? If not, does "average" refer to the plain average over groups, or weighted by sample size?  Just to make sure, for equal sample sizes  you say that if true correlation is 0.3 in two samples and -0.6 in the third, you define that the null hypothesis is fulfilled and should not be rejected?

Comment: Maybe you need to involve prior distributions and go Bayesian...